# data() { ... == data: function() { ...?

Tags: vue.js

Равны ли записи

```
new Vue({
   data() {
         return...
```

и

```
new Vue({
   data: function() {
         return...
```

Comment: @RomanC так понимаю равны..

Comment: Можно еще написать вот так: `data: () => ({})`, вроде это вариант es6

Comment: @Idushii можно, но какой в этом смысл? [почему нельзя](https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/january-2018-room-with-a-vue-part-1)

Comment: Так короче. Когда пишешь этот код на 10 раз, хочется сократить написание.  Вот объяснение запрета в документации https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0, но и тут запрет только для функций, в которых необходимо использовать свойство `this`. Эта функция `this` не использует.

Comment: @Idushii когда не нужно ссылаться на экземпляр функции или когда нужно, чтобы this ссылался на родительский компонент внутри стрелочной функции, а так здорово это ничего не сокращает, если конечно пишешь меньше 10 разxD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да равны, просто первая запись в стиле `ES6+` то есть чтобы объявить метод не надо писать такие слова и ключевые элементы как `:`, `function`, вторая запись идет в стиле `ES5` где методы это по сути свойства равные функциям.